# Can't line ellipse with the coordinates of a vector

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js, euclidean-distance

I'm trying to line up some ellipse with the endpoint of a line that moves and rotates, and the end goal is to be able to calculate the coordinates of said endpoint. I can calculate the initial position, but as soon as I move the car all of the ellipses go in the opposite direction. I'm not great at geometry and I can't figure out why it's doing this or how to fix it.

What I have so far:
`sketch.js`

```
// Declares global variables
const h = window.innerHeight;
const w = window.innerWidth;
var car;
var borders = [];
var pos = {
    x: w / 2, 
    y: h / 2,
    angle: 0
}

function setup () {

    // Creates the canvas
    background ( '#000000' );
    createCanvas ( w, h );
    angleMode ( DEGREES );
    rectMode ( CENTER );
    stroke ( 255 );

    // Creates some borders
    borders.push ( new Border ( 0, height / 2, width, height / 2 ) );

    // Creates the car 
    car = new Car();

}

function draw () {

    // Clears the canvas
    background ( '#000000' );
    fill("white");

    // Displays the borders
    for ( var border of borders ) {
        border.show();
    }

    // Moves the car 
    if ( keyIsDown ( UP_ARROW ) ) {
        car.forward();
    } 

    if ( keyIsDown ( DOWN_ARROW ) ) {
        car.backward();
    }

    // Checks if the car is intersecting
    const intersection = car.intersects ( borders );
    car.emit(borders);
    if ( intersection ) {
        fill("red");
    }


    // Displays the car on the canvas
    translate(pos.x, pos.y);
    rotate(pos.angle);
    car.show();

}
```

`car.js`

```
class Car {

    // Defines the class
    constructor ( ) {

        this.pos = createVector ( 0, 0 );
        this.width = 20;
        this.length = 40;
        this.speed = 0;
        this.rays = [];

        // Creates the car's rays
        for ( var x = 0; x < 360; x += 20 ) {
            this.rays.push ( new Ray ( createVector ( this.pos.x, this.pos.y ), radians ( x ) ) );
        }

    }

    // Displays the car on the canvas
    show () {  

        // Displays the car
        rect ( this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.width, this.length );

        // Displays the rays
        for ( var ray of this.rays ) {
            ray.show();
        }
    }

    // Checks if any rays are intersecting a border
    emit ( borders ) {

        // Loops through all the rays
        for ( var ray of this.rays ) {

            // Loops through all the borders
            for ( var border of borders ) {

                const intersection = ray.intersects ( border );
                if ( intersection ) {

                    console.log(intersection);

                }

            }

        }

    }

    // Moves forward
    forward () {
        pos.y -= cos(pos.angle) * 4; 
        pos.x += sin(pos.angle) * 4;

        // Steers left
        if ( keyIsDown ( LEFT_ARROW ) ) {
            pos.angle -= 3;
        }

        // Steers right
        if ( keyIsDown ( RIGHT_ARROW ) ) {
            pos.angle += 3;
        }
    }

    // Moves backward
    backward () {
        pos.y += cos(pos.angle) * 4; 
        pos.x -= sin(pos.angle) * 4;

        // Steers left
        if ( keyIsDown ( LEFT_ARROW ) ) {
            pos.angle -= 3;
        }

        // Steers right
        if ( keyIsDown ( RIGHT_ARROW ) ) {
            pos.angle += 3;
        }
    }

    // Checks if the car is intersecting any borders
    intersects ( borders ) {

        // Calculates the car's corners
        var corners = [
            createVector ( pos.x - ( this.width / 2 ), pos.y - ( this.length / 2 ) ),
            createVector ( pos.x + ( this.width / 2 ), pos.y - ( this.length / 2 ) ),
            createVector ( pos.x + ( this.width / 2 ), pos.y + ( this.length / 2 ) ),
            createVector ( pos.x - ( this.width / 2 ), pos.y + ( this.length / 2 ) )
        ];

        var sides = [
            [
                corners[0],
                corners[1]
            ],
            [
                corners[1],
                corners[2]
            ],
            [
                corners[2],
                corners[3]
            ],
            [
                corners[3],
                corners[0]
            ]
        ];

        // Loops through each side
        for ( var side of sides ) {

            // Loops through each border
            for ( var border of borders ) {

                var x1 = side[0].x;
                var y1 = side[0].y;
                var x2 = side[1].x;
                var y2 = side[1].y;

                const x3 = border.x.x;
                const y3 = border.x.y;
                const x4 = border.y.x;
                const y4 = border.y.y;

                // Rotates the corners relative to the car
                var tempX1 = x1 - pos.x;
                var tempY1 = y1 - pos.y;
                var tempX2 = x2 - pos.x;
                var tempY2 = y2 - pos.y;
                var rotatedX1 = tempX1 * cos ( pos.angle ) - tempY1 * sin ( pos.angle );
                var rotatedY1 = tempX1 * sin ( pos.angle ) + tempY1 * cos ( pos.angle );
                var rotatedX2 = tempX2 * cos ( pos.angle ) - tempY2 * sin ( pos.angle );
                var rotatedY2 = tempX2 * sin ( pos.angle ) + tempY2 * cos ( pos.angle );
                x1 = rotatedX1 + pos.x; 
                y1 = rotatedY1 + pos.y;            
                x2 = rotatedX2 + pos.x;
                y2 = rotatedY2 + pos.y;

                // Checks if the car is intersecting
                const d = ( x1 - x2 ) * ( y3 - y4 ) - ( y1 - y2 ) * ( x3 - x4 );

                const t = ( x1 - x3 ) * ( y3 - y4 ) - ( y1 - y3 ) * ( x3 - x4 ) / d;

                if ( 0 <= t && t <= 1 ) {
                         return createVector ( x1 + t * ( x2 - x1 ), y1 + t * ( y2 - y1 ) );
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

`ray.js`

```
class Ray {

    // Defines the class
    constructor ( position, angle ) {

        this.pos = position;
        this.angle = angle;
        this.dir = p5.Vector.fromAngle ( angle );

    }

    // Checks if the ray is intersecting a border
    intersects ( border ) {

        // const endpoints = [

        // ];
        

        var x1 = pos.x;
        var y1 = pos.y;
        var x2 = this.dir.x * 100;
        var y2 = this.dir.y * 100;

        const x3 = border.x.x;
        const y3 = border.x.y;
        const x4 = border.y.x;
        const y4 = border.y.y;

        // Rotates the corners relative to the car
        var tempX2 = x2 - pos.x;
        var tempY2 = y2 - pos.y;
        var rotatedX2 = tempX2 * cos ( pos.angle ) - tempY2 * sin ( pos.angle );
        var rotatedY2 = tempX2 * sin ( pos.angle ) + tempY2 * cos ( pos.angle );
        x2 = rotatedX2 + pos.x;
        y2 = rotatedY2 + pos.y;

        /* This is where I'm having difficulty */

        push();
        translate(pos.x, pos.y);
        ellipse(x2, y2, 10);
        pop();

        // const den = ( ( x1 - x2 ) * ( y3 - y4 ) - ( y1 - y2 ) * ( x3 - x4 ) );

        // if ( den == 0 ) {
        //     console.log(1);
        //     return;
        // }

        // var t = ( ( x1 - x3 ) * ( y3 - y4 ) - ( y1 - y3 ) * ( x3 - x4 ) ) / den;
        // var u = ( ( x2 - x1 ) * ( y1 - y3 ) - ( y2 - y1 ) * ( x1 - x3 ) ) / den;

        // if ( 0 <= t && t <= 1 ) {

        //     const x = x1 + t * ( x2 - x1 );
        //     const y = y1 + t * ( y2 - y1 );

        //     // return createVector ( x, y );
        //     ellipse ( x, y, 10 );

        // } 

        // return;
        
    }

    // Displays the ray on the canvas 
    show () {

        push();
        translate(this.pos.x, this.pos.y);
        line(0, 0, this.dir.x * 100, this.dir.y * 100);
        pop();

    }

}
```

`border.js`

```
class Border {

    // Defines the class
    constructor ( x1, y1, x2, y2 ) {

        this.x = createVector ( x1, y1 );
        this.y = createVector ( x2, y2 );

    }

    show () {

        stroke ( 255 );
        line ( this.x.x, this.x.y, this.y.x, this.y.y );

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My interpretation is that in lines 31-36 of ray.js, you're trying to rotate the point `x2, y2` by `pos.angle`. You actually don't need to do any trig in order to do that.

In the trig, you subtracted off `pos` from `this.dir`. But `this.dir` was already a vector whose base was at the position of the car, so the coordinates of `this.dir` were already relative to the position of the car. Here is one solution, where x2 and y2 are initialized with the rotation:

```
var x2 = this.dir.x * 100 * cos ( pos.angle ) - 
    this.dir.y * 100 * sin ( pos.angle );
var y2 = this.dir.x * 100 * sin ( pos.angle ) + 
    this.dir.y * 100 * cos ( pos.angle );
```

As I said above, though, you don't have to do any trig. You can make use of the `.rotate()` method:

```
var x2 = this.dir.copy().rotate(radians(pos.angle)).x * 100;
var y2 = this.dir.copy().rotate(radians(pos.angle)).y * 100;
```

NOTE: you need to convert to radians when using `.rotate()` and other vector methods because `angleMode()` does not affect vectors.

In both of these solutions, you should get rid of lines 31-36.

I think you might run into problems, however, when you try to apply this. Since `x2` and `y2` are *relative to the car's position*, they are not the actual endpoints of the lines drawn on the screen. Rather, they are in a circle of points up by the top left corner. If you were to try to test whether the line segment between x1, y1 and x2, y2 intersects with the line segment between x3, y3 and x4, y4, you would get that it only intersects when the border is between `pos` and the top left corner.

I think what you're actually looking for is

```
var x2 = this.dir.copy().rotate(radians(pos.angle)).x + pos.x;
var y2 = this.dir.copy().rotate(radians(pos.angle)).y + pos.y;
```

NOTE: you would also have to get rid of the translation when you display the ellipses in order for this to look right.
When I uncomment your other code in ray.js, it behaves better in this last version.

Additionally, you seem to multiply `this.dir.x` and `this.dir.y` by 100 every time you refer to them. You can omit this if you make `this.dir` 100 pixels long, which is built into the `.fromAngle()` method:

```
this.dir = p5.Vector.fromAngle(angle, 100);
```

will give you a vector in the proper direction with length 100.